# Single quotes showing as diamond shaped question mark in browsers (no database or PHP)

Tags: html, utf-8, quotes

I am working with a web page in which I switched the character set from iso-8859-1 to utf-8.  The top of the page reads like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>[title of site]</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I am only using ASCII characters in the page, and since utf-8 encoding supersets ASCII, this should be fine.  However, single quotes in the text are showing up as question marks surrounded by black diamonds.  I have verified these are are ASCII single quotes (not straight quotes).

I've read much online that describes solutions to the problem that involve PHP, magic quotes, database configuration, etc.  However, this is a flat HTML page that isn't being rendered by any programs.

Also, many who have this problem are told to switch to UTF-8 to fix the problem.  This is exactly how I *introduced* the problem.

Please look at http://mch.blackcatwebinc.com/src/events.html to see this problem.

Comment: How do those words appear on your database?

Comment: The source of the page does **not** have ASCII single quotes.  Whatever put the text there changed them into something else, if indeed they are ASCII single quotes in the original source (which I sincerely doubt).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only quotes in ASCII are the single quote ' (0x27 or 39) and the double quote " (0x22 or 33). What you have there is an 8-bit encoding that places quotes at 145 (0x91) and 146 (0x92) called CP1252; it's the standard 8-bit Western European encoding for Windows. If what you want is UTF-8, you need to convert that to UTF-8, since it's not valid UTF-8; valid UTF-8 uses multiple bytes for characters above 127 (0x7F), and places the opening and closing quotes at U+2018 and U+2019 respectively.

Comment: You all are correct.  I had reviewed the text in vim, which 'masked symptoms' - showing the quotes as single quotes since it read the file as CP1252.  I did a 'set encoding=utf8' and saved the file, and the single quotes appeared as <92> - i.e., the quotes as their CP1252 hex equivalents.  When changed to ASCII (UTF-8) single quotes, all was right.  I also need to set my IDE, CodeLobster, to save all files in UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

According to the W3C, the `meta charset`

> should appear as close as possible to the top of the head element

From http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#metacontenttype

So, I might try to place the `meta` tag above the `title`.

Also, as mentioned in the first answer by @user1505373, `UTF` is always capitalized and there is no space after the `=` in any of the examples I saw.

Answer (score 1):

Your source code is ***not*** saved in UTF-8 but <strike>Latin1</strike> CP1252, and those quotes are ***not*** simple quotes but U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARKS (encoded in Latin1). Save the source file in UTF-8 and it'll work.

Comment: It's not Latin-1. It's Windows Codepage 1252. For most purposes, CP1252 is a superset of Latin-1, but they're still not the same.

Comment: Alright, whatever it is, it's not UTF-8, even though it's declared as UTF-8. I just switched the browser to Latin-1 and it displayed correctly, which is simply a classical case of the declared encoding and the actual encoding not being the same.

Comment: CP1252 was so often used for Latin-1 that most browsers treat Latin-1 as if it were CP1252, and HTML5 mandates that they do.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix is to change UTF-8 to windows-1252 in the `meta` tag. This works, because the server announces no encoding in the `Content-Type` header, so browsers and other clients will use the one specified in a `meta` tag.

The name windows-1252 is the preferred MIME name for the 8-bit Windows Latin-1 encoding, also known as cp1252 and some other names (often misrepresented as “ANSI”).

As @deceze explains, the actual encoding of the data is windows-1252, not UTF-8. You can alternatively change the actual encoding to UTF-8 by saving the file with a suitable command in your authoring software. But what really matters is that the declared encoding matches the real one.

Yet another possibility is to use “escapes” for the apostrophe, such as `&rsquo;`. They work independently of encoding, but they make the source code less legible.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see between your tag and the one on the site I'm working on is the space after the semicolon and that utf is lowercase on yours. Try capitalizing UTF.

Comment: Just tried it locally - no effect.  Still those question marks there.

Answer (score 0):

All ASCII printable characters have their equivalent HTML Entity Code. Some of these characters are generally supported by most common OS typefaces, some are categorized as Symbols that bring us to your rendering issue.

What you supposedly have there is a *closing single quote*, and in order to get it rightly printed you should use it's entity code, or &#146; respectively.
If it turns to be an *opening single quote*, then you should use &#145; instead.

Note, there's no HTML Entity Name for the two <strike>ASCII</strike> characters (and [some more](http://www.startupinternetmarketing.com/resources/ascii.html)) so you're required to opt the entity code variant.

Comment: There is no such thing as the ASCII closing single quote. Only characters below 128 are ASCII.

Comment: If you have a 21st century's name for it, I'll gladly update the response above. Please, just don't say apostrophe.

Comment: It's a closing single quote. It can be encoded in CP1252 or Unicode or probably several other character encodings. It's not ASCII.

Comment: Please don't recommend using HTML entities to solve encoding mismatches.