# Double quote characters as Octal \223 and \224 on unix sun solaris but the same characters as &#34; html entity on windows. Why?

Tags: html, unix, encoding, character-encoding

On windows I can see `&#34;` entity in a file but the same file when I opened through vi editor I get `\223` and `\224` octal number . How can I get the html entity `&#34;` in unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&#34;` is an ASCII double-quote.  Some programs (in particular browsers on Windows) may improve your experience by showing different characters than what was given.

The examples `\223` and `\224` are using [`cp1252`](http://czyborra.com/charsets/iso8859.html), which has been (mis)equated to ISO-8859-1 for the purpose of HTML standardization:

- [Anything wrong with using windows-1252 instead of UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490197/anything-wrong-with-using-windows-1252-instead-of-utf-8)
- [Single quotes showing as diamond shaped question mark in browsers (no database or PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788712/single-quotes-showing-as-diamond-shaped-question-mark-in-browsers-no-database-o)

The actual Unicode values for these are `U+201C` and `U+201D`, or as HTMl entities `&#8220;` and `&#8221;` respectively.

You can always use `&#34;` in a web page of course.  But using `\223`, etc., may not work as expected.